# What does the bag exactly mean?

Tags: php, laravel, web, concept, bag

I am not sure whether it is a topic or concept in the whole web development context, but when it comes to Laravel, the Php framework, I faced with this word (bag, or error bag) number of times, but I did not understand what does it exactly mean.
Can anyone explain it?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accord to [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#named-error-bags):

If you have multiple forms on a single page, you may wish to name the `MessageBag` containing the validation errors, allowing you to retrieve the error messages for a specific form. To achieve this, pass a name as the second argument to `withErrors`:

```php
return redirect('register')->withErrors($validator, 'login');
```

You may then access the named `MessageBag` instance from the `$errors` variable:

```php
{{ $errors->login->first('email') }}
```